# How to perform a Kolmogorov-Smirnov goodness of fit test on a custom probability density function in python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have an array of experimental values and a probability density function that supposedly describes their distribution:

```
def bekkers(x, a, m, d):
    p = a*np.exp((-1*(x**(1/3) - m)**2)/(2*d**2))*x**(-2/3)
    return(p)
```

I estimated the parameters of my function using scipy.optimize.curve_fit and now I need to somehow test the goodness of fit. I found a scipy.stats.kstest function which suposedly does exactly what I need, but it requires a continuous distribution function. How do I approach my task?

Comment: Are all 4 parameters moving within your experimental data, or only one? The KS-test is structured to test one-dimensional probability distributions, so if you are holding 3 of your four inputs constant you can apply this test, otherwise you may want to try something else (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test).

Comment: @JB333, the x is the independent variable and a, m and d are the fitted parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: I am unsure what your range of possible x values is, as well as what your estimates for a, m, and d are so I tried to leave these as open ended as possible.

---

The CDF for a KS test refers to a *Cumulative* distribution, not a *continuous* distribution function (which you've already got). We'll build a function for that, and since I am not sure if there is a closed form for the integral of the equation you've provided, we'll just do it with scipy.integrate.

For the sake of using it with other numpy/scipy tools we'll want it to receive and return an array (there may be a prettier way to do this, but the below still works). Also note that you'll have to normalize the cdf because, *at least for the values and range I chose*, the integral across the full range of possible values does not equal 1. Here is what it will look like:

```
def bekkers_cdf(x,a,m,d,range_start,range_end):
    values = []
    for value in x:
        integral = integrate.quad(lambda k: bekkers(k,a,m,d),range_start,value)[0]
        normalized = integral/integrate.quad(lambda k: bekkers(k,a,m,d),range_start,range_end)[0]
        values.append(normalized)
    return np.array(values)
```

Once we have this we can now evaluate our ks.test (using some values I made up for the range, and for a, m, and d):

```
my_start,my_end = 1,10
my_a,my_m,my_d = 1,1,1
my_data = [1.5,1.6,1.8,2.1,2.2,3.3,4,6,8,9]
stats.kstest(my_data,lambda x: bekkers_cdf(x,my_a,my_m,my_d,my_start,my_end))
```

This returns:

```
(0.17609125905568074, 0.9157727421346824)
```

The first value is the statistic, and the second is the p-value. With such a high p-value we definitely can't reject that this data came from this distribution.

Code summary:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy import integrate,stats

def bekkers(x, a, m, d):
    p = a*np.exp((-1*(x**(1/3) - m)**2)/(2*d**2))*x**(-2/3)
    return(p)

def bekkers_cdf(x,a,m,d,range_start,range_end):
    values = []
    for value in x:
        integral = integrate.quad(lambda k: bekkers(k,a,m,d),range_start,value)[0]
        normalized = integral/integrate.quad(lambda k: bekkers(k,a,m,d),range_start,range_end)[0]
        values.append(normalized)
    return np.array(values)

my_start = 1
my_end = 10
my_a,my_m,my_d = 1,1,1
my_data = [1.5,1.6,1.8,2.1,2.2,3.3,4,6,8,9]
stats.kstest(my_data,lambda x: bekkers_cdf(x,my_a,my_m,my_d,my_start,my_end))
```

---

For a little fun we can take a peek at what the ks-test is looking at. To do this we plot the theoretical cdf from our data compared to that of the proposed function. (Note that below I hard-coded in the points for the data's cdf, but this would be easy to programmatically) Using matplotlib this is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xs = np.linspace(1, 10)
ys = bekkers_cdf(xs,my_a,my_m,my_d,my_start,my_end)
theoretical, =plt.plot(xs,ys,linewidth=2)
x2s = [1,1.5,1.6,1.8,2.1,2.2,3.3,4,6,8,9,10]
y2s = [0,.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9,1,1]
data, =plt.plot(x2s,y2s,linewidth=2)
plt.legend([theoretical,data],['theoretical','data'])
```

Which yields:

[image: cdf of theoretical vs. data]

We see that the data's cdf is similar to that suggested by the proposed distribution, so it makes sense our test did not reject the null with the sample data came from this distribution.